# Django querysets granularity

Tags: python, django

Assume I have a table with one record per day per person, keeping total calories ate by that person on that day.

Now say that Tom has 30 total days calorie history and Dani has 365 total days calorie history on that table.

How can I run a Django queryset on Dani's calorie history, picking up calorie readings, gathering a total of 30 records, each 10 days apart from each other so that if I run on same code for the two people, I will get for both of them - 30 records and not 30 records for Tom and 365 records for Dani.

i.e: I need granularity in case total record count exceeds 30. If it exceeds 30, I need 10 days (more or less) granularity.

I hope my explanation is understandable.

Comment: I really don't understand. Provide some more concrete examples. What you ask seems more like an algorithm than an SQL query.

Answer (score -1):

I would solve this by writing a custom sql. for postgres I can do something like this

```
select * from
    (select row_number() over(order by id) as row_num, * 
    from calorie
    where user_id = 12345
    order by id) as q
where row_num % ((select count(*) 
          from calorie 
          where user_id = 12345)/30) = 0
```

Here, First I queried a users whole queries and give them row_numbers

```
select row_number() over(order by id) as row_num, * 
        from calorie
        where user_id = 12345
        order by id
```

Then I found out the distance between the rows:

```
((select count(*) 
          from calorie 
          where user_id = 12345)/30)
```

this is for 30 rows if I get less the 30 rows, it will throw division by zero.
then I got the only rows that are divisible by row_distance

```
row_num % row_distance = 0
```

You could also use sampling which seems easier to me. And also work for row numbers less then 30

```
select *
from calorie 
where user_id = 12345
order by random()
limit 30
```

Comment: At the very least you should point to the django docs where it describes writing raw SQL. The answer you gave has nothing to do with the OP's requirements.